# Does there exist an infinite set admitting precisely four linear orders?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, upper-lower-bounds, well-orders

I am studying a course on ZF Set Theory where I encountered the following question:

> Does there exist a set admitting precisely four linear orders?

Since any set with $n$ elements exhibits $n!$ linear orders, it feels obvious to conclude that there does not exist such a set since $n! \neq 4$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (certainly not a finite set).

However, I was wondering if there is a proof (or counterexample) for the claim that is more rigorous than this observation. The question seemed to be posed as more than just a trivial consequence of this fact and so I am assuming that I have oversimplified the problem and that if I broaden my consideration to infinite sets, then it becomes potentially a lot more tricky to conclude that the statement is incorrect in such a simple manner.

I would be grateful for any clarity here.

---

**Further Thoughts**

Having now entertained the possibility of constructing infinite sets that exhibit precisely four linear orders, I have tentatively come up with an example that I think **might** work (**edit:** this does not work).

Perhaps if we define the set $$X := \mathbb{Z} \times \{ 1,2,3,4 \}$$

Then we can define the following four linear orders:

$$ \text{Order 1: $(a, i) <_1 (b, j)$ if and only if $a < b$ or ($a = b$ and $i < j$)}$$

$$ \text{Order 2: $(a, i) <_2 (b, j)$ if and only if $a > b$ or ($a = b$ and $i < j$)}$$

$$ \text{Order 3: $(a, i) <_3 (b, j)$ if and only if $i < j$ or ($i = j$ and $a < b$)}$$

$$ \text{Order 4: $(a, i) <_4 (b, j)$ if and only if $i < j$ or ($i = j$ and $a > b$)}$$

However, I am hesitant to accept this as an answer without first showing that these are indeed the only four possible linear orders here (since the question requires that there are precisely four). It's certainly the case that four is a lower bound here, but how do I show that there are no others (if indeed this is the case)?

---

**Edit**

The above example is not correct. Please refer to the answer I have produced below for the reason why that is the case. Thanks again to @spaceisdarkgreen and @EdwardH for their help in the comments.

Comment: Seems to me that without choice it’s conceivable that there are infinite sets with very few linear orders.

Comment: I'd go with: "If it's totally orderable, then it has at least as many total orders as bijections, of which there are at least $6$ as soon as $3$ elements are there. If it isn't totally orderable, then it has $0$ total orders."

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It's not true that every permutation yields a different order, if that's what you're saying (e.g. $n\mapsto n+1$ on $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: @FD_bfa That doesn't use the axiom of choice.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio (But every permutation that swaps exactly two elements does, so that works.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, I had well-orders in mind and I got completely blindsided to that. Or you can do with the ones that permute only finitely many elements, so you get to $5$ faster.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the claim is false then? Since any set with at least one linear order has at least $|X|$ linear orders, this means that no infinite set can have $4$ linear orders. And then using our reasoning for finite sets having $n!$ linear orders and the fact that $n! \neq 4$ this feels sufficient to argue that the assertion is false? @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @FD_bfa yes, that’s right

Comment: Thanks! The first comment suggests that there are infinite sets with few linear orders without choice. I assume that comment is not correct then (since the reasoning in my above comment suggests that the number of linear orders should be at the very least countably infinite for any infinite set)  @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @FD_bfa Well, the intuition behind that comment isn't wrong... there's more to think about without choice and weird things can be consistent. It just didn't happen that this particular weird thing was consistent. I don't see how you can infer there are at least countably infinitely many linear orders, only that there are at least $|X|$ (infinite does not imply "at least countably infinite" without AC).

Comment: I assumed "$X$ is infinite $\implies |X| \ge \aleph _0$ in $ZF$", but based on your comment I'm assuming that's only guaranteed to be true in $ZFC$? Also, I have written up an answer based on yours and EdwardH's comments. I would be grateful if you could double check to see that I have understood the argument correctly @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @FD_bfa (continuing previous comment) And "very few" is actually right, in the sense that unlike in ZFC, it's consistent in ZF for an infinite set to have zero linear orders, though we've shown any other finite number is impossible. More generally speaking, with choice, it's provable that there are exactly $2^{|X|}$ linear orders for any infinite $X,$ and, at least in the comment section here, we weren't able to get this sharp lower bound in ZF ( under the assumption there are any linear orders on $X$.)

Comment: @FD_bfa Yes, that requires choice. it is equivalent to "every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite", a well-studied weak choice principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The claim is False.** As stated in the question, we can make use of the following lemma as part of the proof of the full claim. This helps us to deal with the case of finite sets (which our main argument will eventually reduce the problem down to):

> **Lemma:** For any finite set $A$ where $|A| = n $, the total number of (strict) linear orders on the set $A$ is equal to $n!$
>
> ***Proof:** A proof of the lemma has already been requested on the site and has been answered with a proof provided. This can be found at [the following link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2540801/1007603).* $ \space \Box$

We are now well equipped to make and prove the following claim with the use of the above lemma (thus showing that the answer to the question is that no such set exists):

> **Proposition:** There are **no** sets that exhibit precisely $4$ linear orders.

***Proof***

- We can prove this by contradiction. Assume that there exists a set $X$ that exhibits precisely four linear orders. Let us denote one of these by $(X, <)$. Then, we can immediately define new linear orders on $X$ by considering $\{ (X, <^b) : b \in X \}$ where $<^b$ is the same as $<$ except, we make the element $b$ our maximal element.
- Therefore, the number of linear orders on $X$ is lower bounded by the cardinality of $X$. As a result, we require $|X| <4$, otherwise our assumption that $X$ has precisely $4$ linear orders would not hold.
- Now that we know that $X$ is a finite set, we can use the fact that any finite set with cardinality $n$ has $n!$ linear orders to complete the proof (since $n! \neq 4$ for any choice of $n \in \mathbb{N}$). This makes direct use of the lemma above.
- The set $X$ must satisfy the following $|X|! = 4$. However, this has no solutions for $|X| \in \mathbb{N}$ and so the cardinality of $X$ is undefined. This is a contradiction since cardinality is defined for all sets. Therefore, no such set $X$ can exist. $\quad \Box$

---

More explicitly, this means that if $|X| = 4,$ then we would have $24$ linear orders. If $|X| = 3,$ we would have $6$ linear orders. If $|X| = 2,$ we would have $2$ linear orders. If $|X| = 1$ or $|X| = 0$, then we would have $1$ linear order. And so it is clear that we cannot have a set that has precisely $4$ linear orders.